# Php SoapClient and adding xmlns url's

Tags: php, xml-namespaces, soap-client

Totally new to using Soap, but I need to understand what is going on because I cannot get my head around this issue.

I need to add two namespaces for my code to work. And for the life of me I cannot get it done.

This is the name spaces I need adding:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:cour="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CourierServiceLibrary">
```

This is the content I am sending:

```
$xml = array(
        'CLIENT_GUID' => 'GUID',
        'Destination' => array(
            'Country2LetterCode' => 'PM',
            'TownCity' => 'tiwb',
            'PostCode' => 'AA112BB',
            'NonDocFlag' => false,
            'ImportFlag' => false
        ),
        'PackageDimensionsMetric' => array(
            'NumberOfPackages'=> 1,
            'Weight' => 9,
            'Length' => 9,
            'Width' => 9,
            'Height' => 9
        )
    );
```

The PHP code I am sending is pretty simple, and looks a bit like this:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://webservice.com/Service.svc?WSDL');
$response = $soapclient->Comparison($xml);
```

I get a response, but because I cannot seem to add the Name-Spaces, what comes back fails to be readable.

I have tried to send a raw text version of the full XML, but that fails with the server rejecting it every-time.  There are lots of old forums that speak of this, but none of the solutions I have tried.

But I did read one that said it was not possible with SoupClient, dated back to 2013.  Is this actually still the case, and this is why I am unable to add the NameSpace?

Note: Using SoupUI, it seems to actually send the whole raw xml which has the xmlns already in it. But when I try it fails.

Any help would be very much appreciated because I cannot see why it wouldn't work when it does in SoupUI.  But I have not used Soup before in any previous project.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question off. I do not really think it's the answer to the question.  But it did resolve the issue I had, by using CURL.

```
$xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"';

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Accept: application/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/************/***********",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
); //SOAPAction: your op URL

$url = $soapUrl;
// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $soapUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
curl_close($ch);
echo "<hr>";
```

I hope this might help someone that might be new to XML, and understanding how to gain data from a call to a Webservice.